# Authorization exception with Azure using C# and Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, authorization, azure-active-directory

I am a student and I am currently trying to learn Azure platform and how to use the C# libraries to manage it.
I was able to create, delete blob and files with no problem using the package WindowsAzure.Storage.

Then I wanted to list VMs using this tutorial : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/csharp

This is my code:

```
var credentials = SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory.FromFile(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_AUTH_LOCATION"));

var azure = Azure
            .Configure()
            .WithLogLevel(HttpLoggingDelegatingHandler.Level.Basic)
            .Authenticate(credentials)
            .WithDefaultSubscription();

Console.WriteLine(azure.VirtualMachines.List().Count());
```

My connection file look like this:

```
subscription=********-****-****-****-************
client=********-****-****-****-************
key=qeFkWjPm0YHn5xw8UMS2ytLhf9Oi0rEMxZVOTpk3aMQ=
tenant=********-****-****-****-************
managementURI=https://management.core.windows.net/
baseURL=https://management.azure.com/
authURL=https://login.windows.net/
graphURL=https://graph.windows.net/
```

But I get this error:

```
Unhandled Exception: Microsoft.Rest.Azure.CloudException: The client '********-****-****-****-************' with object id '********-****-****-****-************' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/read' over scope '/subscriptions/********-****-****-****-************'.
```

There is two weird things I noticed :
1 - In the exception message, the client id and object id are the same and I dont know where they come from.
2 - When I create a new application registration on AzureAD, I can't see it in "My apps" but only in "All Apps", and I cant add myself as an owner.
[Click here to see a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CDpB.png)

I have searched for 2 days and I cant figured out why it's not working.
(This is a simple .Net Core 2 console project, I am on Linux if it can help to find out)

Thank you in advance.

Edit #1 :

Thank's to @juunas, working now.
Help link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal#assign-application-to-role

Comment: Have you added the application to a role in the subscription? :) The error sounds like the app does not have rights to do that in the subscription.

Comment: @juunas Thank you for your answer. What do you mean by adding the application to a role ? Is it about the Access Controler (IAM) ?

Comment: Yeah that one :) To read details about a VM, the application should have a Reader role on the VM, its resource group, or the subscription. If you need to modify things, Contributor allows all modifications.

Comment: @juunas It's working now, thank you a lot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read details about a VM, the application should have a Reader role on the VM, its resource group, or the subscription. If you need to modify things, Contributor allows all modifications. You should add the application to a role via the Access Control IAM tab on the subscription/resource group/resource.